# Magento system.xml case sensitive module name issue

Tags: magento-1.9, module, system.xml, system-config, system-configuration

I have created a custom controller in custom module in Magento ce-1.9.2.4.
Module name is given in camelcase as I want to try if Magento accepts camel-case module name in `system.xml` also other than `config.xml`.

But when I create the `system.xml` as below it doesn't create tab in `System >> Configuration` page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <custom translate="label" module="myModule">
            <label>Custom FirmInfo</label>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        </custom>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <myModule translate="label" module="myModule">
            <label>Mymodule</label>
            <tab>Autofill</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <settings translate="label">
                    <label>Settings</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enable translate="label">
                            <label>Enable</label>
                            <comment><![CDATA[Enable or Disable this extension.]]></comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enable>
                    </fields>
                </settings>
            </groups>
        </myModule>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Please can anybody let me know what could be the issue with the `system.xml` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it has nothing to do with the case here.

An evident problem is your code is that you declare your new tab like this:

```
<tabs>
    <custom translate="label" module="myModule">
        <label>Custom FirmInfo</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </custom>
</tabs>
```

But when you assign your section to your tab you don't assign the right tab:

```
<tab>Autofill</tab>
```

To fix that you should replace this code with:

```
<tab>custom</tab>
```

As `custom` is the id of the tab you created.